# Why am I getting this result from 32 bit NASM assembly code?

Tags: linux, assembly, printf, nasm

My NASM assembly code (in Linux) is as follows:

```
   %macro write_string 2
    push %1
    call printf
    pop eax
    add esp, %2
    %endmacro
section .text
   global main            ;must be declared for using gcc
   extern printf
main:
   push ebp
   mov ebp, esp
   write_string msg1, len1
   write_string msg2, len2
   write_string msg3, len3
   mov esp, ebp
   pop ebp

 mov eax,1                ;system call number (sys_exit)
  int 0x80                 ;call kernel

section .data
msg1  db 'Hello, programmers!',0xA,0xD
len1  equ $ - msg1
msg2  db 'Welcome to the world of,', 0xA,0xD
len2  equ $- msg2
msg3  db 'Linux assembly programming! '
len3  equ $- msg3
```

When this is executed (after nasm -f elf -o writeStrings.o writeStrings.asm && gcc -o writeStrings writeStrings.o), I get the following output:

> ```
> Hello, programmers! Welcome to the world of, Linux assembly
> programming! Welcome to the world of,
> ```

Can anyone tell me why the "Welcome to the world of," is getting duplicated?

Any help would be appreciated!

**Update:**
After adding the 0x00 after each msg, now the output is:
Hello, programmers!
Welcome to the world of,

The third print is not outputting now.

**Update:**
I was able to get it working.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: `printf` prints until it find a NUL character (value 0x00).Your string aren't NUL terminated

Comment: Try adding a `, 0x00` at the end of each msg

Comment: As well this is wrong `add esp, %2` you are not suppose to add  the length to ESP after `printf`

Comment: The reason the last one likely wasn't printing was because the _C_ library buffered the output and using the `syscall` to exit prevented it from being output to the console. You'd probably have to add a new line character after or better yet replace the exit `syscall` with `ret` to return from `main` back to the _C_ library where the buffers will be flushed and program terminated.

Comment: `0x0d, 0x0a` is a DOS CR LF line ending.  Unix / Linux uses a single line-feed (0x0a).  Do don't need to, and shouldn't, put a CR at the beginning of the next line.